# How can I install Nominatim OSM geocoder on Google App engine?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

How can I install Nominatim on GAE? I've found a small amount of relevant information searching the internet, even with examples, but they are showing how to install it on VM, with os like Ubuntu. I wondering because I need to get places names by providing it with latitude and longitude.

P.S: I've searched this site for a case somebody asked this question before, but I haven't found something relevant.

Comment: I think the main question is, if you can install Nominatim _at all_ on GAE. According to the official documentation on https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/ it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine is a special layer on top of underlying real VMs. It has very restricted APIs (comparable to what you get from naked machine) and only specially designed software could be run on GAE.

If you want to run Nominatim on Google cloud infrastructure you should look at Google Compute Engine (https://cloud.google.com/compute/). This is could VM where you can install all kinds of software including Postgres if you want to manage it manually.